# How do I get all data from firebase into list<myObject>

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with Google Firebase. While working on my project I have a object like this.

```
public class Travel implements Serializable {
     private String title;
     private String location;
     private int duration;
     private String description;
     private ArrayList<String> tags;
     private String dateAdded;
     private int rating;
     private int databaseID;
     //getters and setters are the only methods
}
```

and my Firebase database looks like this after uploading data

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvWYM.png)

Code to upload the data is :

```
FirebaseHandler fb = new FirebaseHandler();
fb.addOnline(travel);
```

Now I want to make an   ArrayList
with the data in firebase database.

I have watched the tutorial [Here](https://youtu.be/2duc77R4Hqw)
But this is a simple 2 level hierarchy.

My question is how do I iterate through the **DataSanpshot** to create the ArrayList?

Comment: What do you mean by `Now I want to make an ArrayList
with the data in firebase database.`? What is your expected data structure?

Comment: The expected data structure is given on the first code snippet.. Its an object "Travel" ..  Please see the first Class. @UmarZaii

Comment: @Shafi: Umar is more likely asking about the JSON structure in your database. Please edit your question to include the minimum sample of the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Aside from that: iterating through the snapshot for a value event is shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in our `DataSnapshot` is listening an array in your Firebase DB, you can iterate it this way:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    list.add(item.getValue(YourObject.class));
}
```

Note you can "parse" the DataSnapshot value to your concrete domain class.

Comment: Solved. Although needed to navigate to child for "users" and currently firebase authorized user.

Comment: `ArrayList<Travel> fireBaseList = new ArrayList<>();
            DataSnapshot thisUser = dataSnapshot.child(currentUser.toString());
            for (DataSnapshot thisUserData : thisUser.getChildren()){
                Travel travel = thisUserData.getValue(Travel.class);
                fireBaseList.add(travel);
            }`

Answer (score 0):

create the arrayList of the string type dataType like this:

```
Query citiesQuery = databaseRef.child("cities").startAt(input).orderByValue();
    citiesQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                cities.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
```

Hope it will help you out..